# Coefficient stability between two different models

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

I have applied two different models. One OLS model with independent variables X1, X2, X3 and one ridge model with independent variables X1, X2, X3, X4 and X5 through glmnet package in R. So let’s say for OLS model we receive the following `Y = a1 + b1*X1 + c1*X2 + d1*X3` and from ridge model for different lambda we receive `Y = a2 + b2*X1 + c2*X2 + d2*X3 + e*X4 + f*X5`. Is there any way to test the null hypothesis that H0:a1=a2, b1=b2, c1=c2? More specifically I want to apply this test for all different models of all lambda with OLS.

I tried to apply a chow test but I do not think that this test works for this issue.

Comment: Isn't it easier to test that e, f=0 in the second case? Also, if X1, X2, X3 are not linearly independent there may be more than one way to combine them linearly to get the same prediction for Y

Answer (score 0):

Looking at basic description of [ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression) it seems this is about finding coefficients $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ for the linear model:

$$
y=\mathbf{x}^T.\boldsymbol{\beta}+\epsilon
$$

Where $y$ is the dependent variable $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of independent variables and $\epsilon$ is noise. We don't need to know the distribution of noise for regression, but for things like standard errors we will need it. In [Chow test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test) the residuals are assumed to be normally distributed, so we might as well assume it here: $\epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,\sigma^2)$.

Given measured vector of dependent variable $\mathbf{Y}$ and design matrix with independent variable measurements $\mathbf{X}$, the estimator for the ridge regression is:

$$
\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}=\left(\mathbf{X}^T.\mathbf{X}+\lambda\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1}.\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{A}.\mathbf{Y}
$$

Where $\lambda\ge0$ is your regularization constant (known). Treating $\mathbf{Y}$, and the estimator as a random variables, given $\mathbf{X}$, their distributions are:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Y}\,\big|\,\mathbf{X},\lambda&\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta},\,\sigma^2\mathbf{I}\right)\\
\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\,\big|\,\mathbf{X},\lambda&\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta},\,\sigma^2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T\right)
\end{align}
$$

Both OLS and ridge regression can be treated under this framework, the former with $\lambda=0$. So then your question becomes a question about comparing coefficients from two $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$. The two could have different variances and different means.

I guess you want to test that some means of the coefficients from two $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ are different. This boils down to comparing means from two different multivariate distributions. If you assume equality of variance, you will end up with some version of a t-Test. Uni-variate or multi-variate depending on how you choose your null hypothesis. I am sure there is plenty of literature on this, starting from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).

More generally, you may end up with some version of [Welch's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). I would probably go with something Bayesian instead, i.e. estimate the probability distribution for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ given what you have observed, and then estimate the probability that the two beta-s are equal within some margin.